# Create folder from specific multiple files, and then move specific multiple files into it

Tags: windows, batch

I have some files

```
07-01.jpg
07-02.jpg until
07-48.jpg


37-01.jpg
37-02.jpg
37-03.jpg until37-48.jpg
```

I want to create folder

```
07, 08.... ,37
```

and then move multiple files

```
07-01.jpg, 07-02.jpg, 07-03.jpg into folder 07
08-01.jpg, 08-02.jpg, 08-03.jpg into folder 08
37-01.jpg, 37-02.jpg, 37-03.jpg into folder 37
etc
```

how would a batch script look like to acchieve this?

thanks

Comment: It is unlikely that a batch script exists that does exactly this, so you would need to write one.

Answer (score 1):

No batch file needed:

```
for %F in (*-*.jpg) do @for /f "delims=-" %A in ("%F") do @md "%A" 2>nul&move /y "%F" "%A" >nul
```

Double up the percents if used within a batch script.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
@echo off
setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion
rem parameter 1: first prefix (e.g 7)
rem parameter 2: last prefix (e.g 37)
rem parameter 3: max counter (e.g. 48)
FOR /L %%A IN (%1,1,%2) DO (
    rem arrange the padding
    set pre=0%%A
    set pre=!pre:~-2!
    rem create the folder
    mkdir !pre!
    FOR /L %%B IN (1,1,%3) DO (
        rem arrange the padding
        set num=0%%B
        set num=!num:~-2!
        rem file name
        set curr_file=!pre!-!num!.jpg
        rem ECHO !curr_file!
        move !curr_file! !pre!
    )
)
```

Save in a batch file (e.g. `store_files.bat`) and invoke it with proper params:

```
store_files.bat 7 37 48
```

-

Edit: the solution of dbenham is more elegant.